# Is there a way to Inject to the cucumber step variable from the scenario scope in cucmber

Tags: javascript, cucumberjs

I am looking for a way in cucumber.js to store a value in the scenario scope and then reuse it in the feature file as a step parameter like the following example:

**Then I expect that element "element" matches the text {{scenarioscopeveribale[A]}}**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the [World](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/world.md#world) the intended way of sharing between scenarios, what you put in your world, though "this", is going to be shared between scenarios.